# How to create a logic hook in SuiteCRM based a custom module 'ProductInvestigation' subpanel of Cases

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using a custom module called ProductInvestigation and Cases module; when the user adds/deletes a case from the subpanel; I would like to send an email. It has a one to many relationship. The logic I'm thinking of is that if the cases status is **new**  and ProductInvestigation status is **InvestigationClosed** then it should send out an email. Function **createPIEmailwithCases** is what I would like to use to send the email. But how do I get the data from the relationship to be send in the email. Is it that function **before_add** and **after_add** should be in this function **createPIEmailwithCases**? This is what I have so far.

```
function before_add($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
         if ($arguments['related_module'] =='Cases')
         {
            $bean->new_case_c =$arguments['related_id'];
          
            
            
            $case_bean = BeanFactory::getBean('Cases', $arguments['related_id']);
            
            /* Get PI Status */
            $pi_status=trim($bean->getFieldValue('status_c'));
            
        
            if ($case_bean->status_c = "New" && $pi_status='Investigation_Closed' ) 
            {
                   
            }
        }
    }
    
    function after_add($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
     if ($arguments['related_module'] =='Cases'){
        $bean->new_case_c =$arguments['related_id'];
      
        $bean->save();

     }
    } 


*function createPIEmailwithCases(&$email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl){
    
    /* Get PI Number */

    $xtpl->assign('PI_Number', $bean->pinum_c);
    
    /* Get PI Subject */
    $xtpl->assign('PI_Subject', $bean->name);
    
    /* Get Product Name */
    $xtpl->assign('Product_Name', $bean->product_name_c);
    
    /* Get Product Type */
    $xtpl->assign('Product_Type', $bean->type_of_product_c);
    
    /* Get Batch # */
    $xtpl->assign('Batch_Number', $bean->batch_c);
    
    /* Get Size(s) */
    $xtpl->assign('Size', $bean->size_c);
    
    /* Get Fill Date */
    $xtpl->assign('Fill_Date', $bean->filldate_c);
    
    /* Get Batch # */
    $xtpl->assign('BestBefore', $bean->bestbefore_c);

    /* Get PI Description */
    $xtpl->assign('PI_Desc', $bean->description);
    
            
    /* Get Reviewer Name */
    $xtpl->assign('Reviewed_By',$bean->reviewer_c);
    
    $xtpl->assign('Review_Date',$bean->reviewdate_c);

    
    
    /* Create email message using email template and data above */
    $xtpl->parse('block');
    $email->Body = from_html($xtpl->text('block'));
    
    return $email;
}
```

- 

Answer (score 1):

SuiteCRM provides different types of hook and in this case, you can use following relationship hooks.

1. after_relationship_add
2. after_relationship_delete

Support URL: https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/logic-hooks/